# Click and hold in PyGTK?

Tags: touch, pygtk

Is there any way to detect a click and hold event in PyGTK? I'm in a touch environment, and I want to pop up a context menu from a button if I hold the button down longer than a second or so, since I can't do a right-click or ctrl-click.

If there isn't an easy way, I suppose I could make the mouse press event start a GTK timeout that would activate the menu, and cancel it in the mouse release handler. But if the timeout fires, how would I cancel the mouse press so that the eventual mouse release wouldn't trigger the button click event?

Comment: Does the solution need to be OS independent? If not, which OS are you on?

Answer (score 3):

bohrax: After trying that, and beating on it for a while, it mutated into something pretty clean. Maybe someone else can make it even cleaner.

```
class HoldButton(gtk.Button):

    __gsignals__ = { 'held' : (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, gobject.TYPE_NONE, ()) }

    def __init__(self, label=None, stock=None, use_underline=True):
        gtk.Button.__init__(self, label, stock, use_underline)
        self.connect('pressed', HoldButton.h_pressed)
        self.connect('clicked', HoldButton.h_clicked)
        self.timeout_id = None

    def h_clicked(self):
        if self.timeout_id:
            gobject.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
            self.timeout_id = None
        else:
            self.stop_emission('clicked')

    def h_pressed(self):
        self.timeout_id = gobject.timeout_add(750, HoldButton.h_timeout, self)

    def h_timeout(self):
        self.timeout_id = None
        self.emit('held')
        return False
```

This starts a timeout in the "pressed" handler. If it is still pending in the "clicked" handler, the timeout is canceled, otherwise the "clicked" signal is terminated with `stop_emission`. Then I had to figure out how to define a new signal, "held", which is emitted in the timeout handler.

Comment: I like that you managed to encapsulate the behavior. Wasn't aware of the stop_emission function before.

Comment: Hey, i would like to test the whole script in my touchscreen (Debian). Do you have the script available in github ?

Comment: The GTK people have deprecated several of these functions: `self.stop_emission('clicked')` should become `self.stop_emission_by_name('clicked')`. You should (if you hadn't already) import `GLib` like `from gi.repository import GLib` and use `GLib.timeout_add` with the same parameters. Nothing major, just thought I'd drop this note here for after the functions get removed so people know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest and most portable way would be to use your approach together with a state flag that informs if a "long-click" is in progress. Instead of connecting to the 'clicked' signal of the button you can use 'released' instead and check the value of the flag in that handler.

Comment: Oh bugger. This doesn't actually work in Windows on a touchscreen. When you touch a button, you don't get a "pressed" event. Instead, when you touch and release, you get "pressed", "clicked" and "released" in rapid succession. If you press and hold, the OS puts up a box, indicating that releasing will pop up a context menu, and when you release, PyGTK emits none of those three events.